# How to get file path using file descriptor on Android?

Tags: java, android, file, file-descriptor

I need to get file absolute path using file descriptor which was returned by [getFileDescriptor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#getFileDescriptor%28%29).
How can i do it?

Comment: Nice idea for investigating those USB device files!  If you build a debug apk, you can use adb shell 'run-as your.package.name' to get a shell as the app's userid and then while it is running use ls -l from that shell on the app process's /proc entries to examine the fd links, rather than having to figure out how to do so from java.

Comment: Chris can you explain more in detail , i also trying get USB OTG path from java code but i am unable to fine it's actual path as google has lot's of restriction for removable device.

Answer (score 1):

On a system running under a Linux kernel, which would be all *current* Android implementations, each file descriptor will have an entry in `/proc/[processid]/fd` which is a symbolic link to the target of the file descriptor - not only for regular files, but also for many other possible targets such as pipes and sockets.

Here's a partial example for a `cat > /mnt/sdcard/foo` process running on an android device

```
$ ls -l /proc/3528/fd
lrwx------ shell    shell             2013-06-06 10:31 0 -> /dev/pts/1
l-wx------ shell    shell             2013-06-06 10:31 1 -> /mnt/sdcard/foo
lrwx------ shell    shell             2013-06-06 10:31 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ shell    shell             2013-06-06 10:31 6 -> socket:[188850]
```

Reading symbolic links in Java "is left as an exercise to the reader".

On a desktop linux, there's the `lsof` tool which trolls through these directories for all processes and dumps out a list of open files - however, that would not be too useful on Android where the usage of per-app userids would restrict such trolling.  But you can still lookup the fd's belonging to your app itself, or any other process running under the same userid.