# Is there any way to get directly file path on Android Q & above?

Tags: android, kotlin

My application need to show media files using direct file paths (ex : **/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/example.png**), but I am facing some problem as below:

- With MediaStore: The column MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA is deprecated
- With Files API : When I perform sequential reads of media files using direct file paths, I can get the root directory because `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated

Can anyone help me find out the best solution?
Thanks advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get real path from Uri - DATA is deprecated in android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093479/get-real-path-from-uri-data-is-deprecated-in-android-q)

Comment: (or in other words: no, there is not a way to do this reliably)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am working with [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) as a simple webserver to serve files, but this library return file as format: `ipAdress:port/{directly file path}`. This is why I need direct file path

Comment: Would the relative path do the trick? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58669414/208273