# GetRealPath for image Android10

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to get real path for Picked image in Android 10 but it's not working Iam using the folowing code its work fine in android 9

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Android.Net.Uri contentUri)
        {
            ICursor cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            String document_id = cursor.GetString(0);
            document_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
            cursor.Close();

            cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(
            Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " = ? ", new string[] { document_id }, null);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            String path = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data));

             cursor.Close();
            return path;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option1

After SDK 29.0 ,`DATA` is deprecated . Apps may not have filesystem permissions to directly access this path. Instead of trying to open this path directly, apps should use `ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri, String)` to gain access.

Here is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093479/get-real-path-from-uri-data-is-deprecated-in-android-q) which you can refer .

### Option 2

You could install the plugin **Xam.Plugin.Media** from nuget .

#### Usage

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
{
     return;
}

var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

if (file == null)
     return;

var path = file.Path;
```

For more details about the plugin you could check https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin